# multidimensional array json_decode (first level)

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "numeric1": {
        "id": "numeric1",
        "name": "alphanumeric1",
        "key": "alphanumeric2",
        "expire": "alphanumeric3",
        "status": true,
        "ads": true
    },

    etc...
}
```

with (etc...) I mean that matrix is repeated more times.
I parse it with PHP using:

```
$allowed = json_decode(file_get_contents("allowed.json"), true);
```

Then I get an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => numeric1
            [name] => alphanumeric1
            [key] => alphanumeric2
            [expire] => alphanumeric3
            [status] => 1
            [ads] => 1
        )

     etc....
 )
```

So I lose the first level of associative keys, I have

```
 [0] => Array
```

instead of

```
 ["numeric1"] => Array
```

How can I keep the first level of my JSON array? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a second element in your JSON example?  Would that element have property value of `numeric2` for example?

Comment: yes would be "numeric2", then "numeric3" etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$allowed = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents("allowed.json"));
```

So instead of directly parsing the JSON as an array (by specifying second parameter of json_decode), first get the object that will preserve the key, then cast as an array.